# Will_paginate changing my routes in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Im currently working  on a Rails 3 application using Will_Paginate and the following route:

```
get 'category/:categories/:page', action: :categories, defaults: { page: nil }
```

I'm trying to use Pretty URL's and the gem is generating them correctly on the view. For example Page 2 link is:

```
www.example.com/category/hats/2
```

Yet when I try to access that link the URL is automatically changed to

```
www.example.com/category/hats?page=2
```

Even if I copy pase the correct link in the browser the URL is changed before its been processed and the server reads:

```
Started GET "/category/hats?page=2" for 127.0.0.1
```

I've searched for any redirects in before_filters and found nothing so far. Im starting to think this may be the default's gem behavior? Is there any way I could log the whole http request to see where exactly is the code responsible for this?

Answer (score 0):

The code is in your controller when you invoke the .paginate(params[:page]) method on your instance variable.